# Tsvector de postgres en Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-5, postgresql

necesito crear un campo tsvector (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-textsearch.html) de postgres en mi tabla **Documentos** ya busque en varios lugares como hacerlo pero no lo encuentro.

```
Schema::create('documentos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('minimagen');
        $table->string('fecha');
        $table->longText('bytes');
        //$table->string('mytsvector');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay algún método o función para crear dicho tipo de campo en Laravel a través de migraciones, la única opción es usando SQL "puro" en la misma:

```
Schema::create('documentos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('nombre');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->string('minimagen');
    $table->string('fecha');
    $table->longText('bytes');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();
});
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE documentos ADD COLUMN mytsvector tsvector');
```

Comment: muchas gracias esto me sirvió, te agradecería si también me dejaras un ejemplo de como hacer una consulta básica a esa columna ya que es la primera ves que veo este tipo de dato

Comment: Solo una cosilla @Shaz te falto una comilla en **mytsvector tsvector);** . Te dejo mis puntos.